# Inconsistencies in plotting piecewise functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

For a mathematics course for first year university science students we (the teaching assistants) need to prepare material for pc-sessions using Matlab. All computers are equipped with Matlab version R2016b.

**We are working through some material from the previous years. In the section covering the plotting of piecewise functions, we found some inconsistencies in the way Matlab handles an `if` condition.**

I would like to know why these things happen so we are prepared for any difficulties the students might experience in these sessions. The goal of the exercise is to draw a house in the plotting window by plotting two piecewise functions.

---

The first function, `f1(x)`, evaluates to `x+2` when `x <= 0` and evaluates to `-x+2` otherwise. The students are asked to implement this function in Matlab using an `if`/`else` construct. Our implementation is

```
function y = f1( x )
    if x < 0
        y = x + 2;
    else
        y = -x + 2;
    end
end
```

The second function, `f2(x)`, is the characteristic function of the interval [-1, 1]. It should also be implemented using `if`/`else` conditions. Our implementation is

```
function y = f2( x )
    if x < -1
        y = 0;
    elseif x > 1
        y = 0;
    else
        y = 1;
    end
end
```

Finally, the plotting code should draw both functions on the interval `[-1.5, 1.5]` using `fplot` like so

```
fplot(@f1, [-1.5, 1.5])
hold on
fplot(@f2, [-1.5, 1.5])
```

---

The function `f2` is plotted without problems. **In plotting `f1`, however, it seems Matlab decided the first branch of the if-clause didn't matter as only the line `-x+2` is plotted**.

It seems vectorization issues lie at the heart of our problem since `f1(-1)` evaluates correctly to 1 but `f1([-1, 1])` evaluates to `[3, 1]`. Then again, f2 seems to be evaluating correctly without any issues.

Things get stranger when we change the `-x + 2` in the `else` part of `f1` to `-x^2 + 2`. With this definition both functions are plotted correctly and Matlab seems to have no problem dealing with the conditionals.

1. What is going wrong?
2. Is there a way we can edit the exercises such that it never poses any problems but is still accessible to students having their first experiences with Matlab?

Comment: If (logical_vector) takes the branch depending on all elements, for all elements. It is the same as if (all(logical_vector)). Try the following: `f1(1)`
`f1(-1)`
`f1([-1, 1])`
`f1([1, -1])`
`f1([1, -1, 1])`
As for your problem - on 2015a it plots the house just fine, so I can't help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MATLAB `if vector` is like `if all(vector)`, and that is the source to your error. use indexing instead:

```
function y = f2( x )
y = zeros(size(x));  
idxs1 = x >= -1;
idxs2 = x <= 1;
y(idxs1 & idxs2) = 1;
end

function y = f1( x )
y = zeros(size(x));  
idxs = x < 0;
y(idxs) = x(idxs) + 2;
y(~idxs) = -x(~idxs) + 2;
end

fplot(@f1, [-1.5, 1.5])
hold on
fplot(@f2, [-1.5, 1.5])
```

[image]

Comment: _In MATLAB `if vector` is like `if all(vector)`_ unless the vectror is empty

Answer (score 0):

**Using an If Statement**

You say that you want to specifically use an `if` structure, in which case you will have to evaluate each element of the input vector in turn

```
function y = f1( x )
y = zeros(size(x));  % Initialise y to the correct size
for ii = 1:numel(x)  % Loop through elements of x (and so y)
    if x(ii) < 0
        y(ii) = x(ii) + 2;
    else
        y(ii) = -x(ii) + 2;
    end
end
end
```

This is because otherwise you may have the following issue:

```
x = [1, 2, -1, 3, -2];
% x < 0 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1];
% "if x < 0" is the same as "if all(x < 0)" = false, so if statement skipped
```

**Logical Indexing**

If the course material can be changed / extended, then a much better option in Matlab is to leverage logical indexing.

```
x = [1, 2, -1, 3, -2];
y = -x + 2;     % Initialise variable y, assign its values to -x + 2 by default
y(x<0) = x + 2; % Assign values of y, where x<0, to x + 2
```

Now it can be seen how this can be done in a one liner...

```
coef = (x < 0)*2 - 1; % For the above example, coef = [-1, -1, 1, -1, 1];
y = coef.*x + 2;      % Coeff can be done in-line without being declared
```

So, with a similar (but even simpler) approach to `f2` as well,

```
function y = f1(x)
    y = ((x<0)*2 - 1).*x + 2;
end

function y = f2(x)
    y = (abs(x) < 1);  
end
```

Then your demo gives the desired result

[image: house]

---

As for your mysteries when changing part of the piecewise function and everything working... For me, your code all works anyway (2015b)! My guess is that this is something to do with how `fplot` is calling your functions. I currently can't access the docs, which may contain the answer. In my above examples, I'm assuming `x` is being passed as a vector (which may have 1 or more elements). If `fplot` determines the `x` values and calls the function as if for single points, then your code should work.

**A way to edit the task to make things clearer may be to just use the normal `plot` function**, which I think is more useful for students to be familiar with anyway.

Then your demo would be called like so

```
x = -1.5:0.1:1.5  % or could use linspace(-1.5, 1.5, 100) etc
hold on;
plot(x, f1(x));   % x,y syntax, more apparent where the points will be plotted
plot(x, f2(x));   %   than when using fplot
hold off;         % good habit to hold off so that you don't accidentally plot on this fig later
```

Notice that, with this clear definition of `x`, your `-x^2 + 2` would throw an error as you are asking for *matrix* multiplication of a 1D vector. You would actually have to use `-x.^2 + 2`. There's a cue for students to learn about element-wise operations in Matlab!